# R How to perform math operation on Regular Expression matches

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I'm working on a data frame that has non-detects (with different decimal separators), missing and measured values.
I want to replace the non detects with half of the value after the less sign (<1 becomes 1/2=0.5).

1) I convert to charactes the imported dataframe.

```
df = data.frame(value=c("NA", "1.2", "<1.0", "<6,6"))
```

1) convert factor to character

```
  df <- data.frame(lapply(df, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

2) I replace all "," to "."

```
 pattern = ","
 grep(pattern, df, value = TRUE)
 df <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {gsub(pattern=pattern, replacement=".", x, perl = TRUE)}))
```

3) I can find all non-detecs and I can replace it with the value after the less sign

```
 pattern = "(^<)(\\d+)"
 grep(pattern, df, value = TRUE)
 df <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {gsub(pattern=pattern, replacement="\\d", x, perl = TRUE)}))
```

I can't find how to perform math operation to the replacement string matched, something as:

```
 replacement = as.character((as.numeric("\\2"))/2)
```

Comment: Sorry, but what are you trying to get in the end? Divide all numbers not preceded with `<` by 2? Why is there a regex pattern in the replacement? There, you can only use a replacement pattern, no `\d` like patterns can be used in the replacement patterns.

Comment: It is rather unclear from your description, could you add some data for example and clarify what you are asking ?

Comment: Step 2: `df$value = gsub(",", ".", df$value, fixed = TRUE)`.  Then `library(gsubfn)` and then `gsubfn("(^|[^<\\d.])(\\d*\\.?\\d+)", function(x,y) paste0(x,as.numeric(y)/2), df$value)`, right?

Comment: ? trying to get a dataframe as this `df = data.frame(value=c("NA", "1.2", "0.5", "3.3"))`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I change your suggestion code into `gsubfn("(^<)(\\d*\\.?\\d+)", function(x,y) paste0(as.numeric(y)/2), df$value)`

Comment: Ah, yes, I see you do not need the `<`. I updated the code in my answer to  simplify it a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code in Step 2:

```
df$value = gsub(",", ".", df$value, fixed = TRUE)
```

It will replace literal commas with literal dots in the `value` column.

Then, you may use the [`gsubfn` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/index.html) to match and manipulate substrings matched with regex:

```
> library(gsubfn)
> df$value = gsubfn("^<(\\d*\\.?\\d+)", ~ as.numeric(x)/2, df$value)
> df
  value
1    NA
2   1.2
3  0.5
4  3.3
```

Here, `^<(\\d*\\.?\\d+)` will match `<` at the start of the string and `\\d*\\.?\\d+` pattern will match and capture into Group 1 any float/integer value and will divide it by 2 later in the callback function.